# sklearn Clustering: Fastest way to determine optimal number of cluster on large data sets

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-mining, bigdata

I use [KMeans](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) and the [silhouette_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html) from sklearn in python to calculate my cluster, but on >10.000 samples with >1000 cluster calculating the silhouette_score is very slow.

1. Is there a faster method to determine the optimal number of cluster?
2. Or should I change the clustering algorithm? If yes, which is the best (and fastest) algorithm for a data set with >300.000 samples and lots of clusters ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most common method to find number of cluster is elbow curve method. But it will require you to run KMeans algorithm multiple times to plot graph. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set wiki page mentions some common methods to determine number of clusters.

Comment: Also you could use an algorithm which does not require the number of clusters as input. DBSCAN or HDBSCAN should scale fine to your dataset size.

Comment: Is there a way to find the number of cluster with the elbow curve method automatically?

Comment: As per my understanding, A program should be able to provide number of cluster based on elbow curve heuristics.

Answer (score 5):

The silhouette score, while one of the more attractive measures, iw O(n^2). This means, computing the score is much more expensive than computing the k-means clustering!

Furthermore, **these scores are only heuristics**. They will not yield "optimal" clusterings by any means. They only give a **hint** on how to choose k, but very often you will find that other k is much better! So **don't trust these scores blindly**.

Answer (score 0):

MiniBatchKmeans is one of the popular option you can try
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html